# UTF-8 locale in Visual C++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-c++, utf-8

I am trying to read a UTF-8 text file in Visual C++ 2010 using only the standard library and not Boost or Windows APIs. I define the locale as:

```
std::locale utf8_locale(std::locale(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>);
```

but this results in the following compiler error:

```
error C2661: 'std::locale::facet::operator new' : no overloaded function takes 3 arguments
error C2664: 'std::locale::locale(const char *,std::locale::category)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::locale' to 'const char *'
```

Comment: You have to fix your code not to get compile error.

Comment: Show us the compiler error and a bit more code.

Comment: I added the compiler error to the question

Comment: I used your code (thanks!), but then I realized that I think there's a memory leak with your 2nd parameter (new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>).  I'm new to C++, so I could be wrong

Comment: Aside from your problem you want to use `std::codecvt_utf8_utf16`

Comment: My question to you is why you want to convert it into UTF-16 in memory. Just read as is, as byte array. Conversion to UTF-16 should be done when interacting with windows APIs, such as display and file open, it is much more efficient. See http://utf8everywhere.org

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is occures in debug mode when the code is used in the file that micrsoft Visual c++ provided below macro is placed.

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif
```

to get rid of this error the `#define new DEBUG_NEW` should be commented out or the code should be implemented in another file which does not have the above macro.
This bug for Visual c++ 2010 is mentioned here http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/683483/mfc-c-fails-to-compile-use-of-codecvt-utf8-in-debug-configuration

Comment: This is only a problem for MFC. Unless you're using MFC, don't link to the MFC libraries. And yes, it's only defined for the debug version of the MFC libraries.

Comment: FWIW and IIRC, in C++ is illegal to define a macro with the name of a reserved word, such as `new`. So this code is yet another abuse of C++ by MFC.

Answer (score 3):

FYI, another work around is to just write

```
std::locale utf8(std::locale(), ::new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>);
```

That will force the compiler to use the global new, instead of the locale new